# How do I construct a ConstraintViolationException in Bean Validation 1.0?

Tags: java, generics, bean-validation

I am puzzled by the javax.validation API. I am writing a simple test to understand it:

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
Set<ConstraintViolation<Sample>> violations = validator.validate(sample);
if (!violations.isEmpty()) {
    // Eclipse refuses to let me use my violations variable
    throw new ConstraintViolationException(violations);
}
```

How should I declare the set of violations so I can use it in my exception constructor?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can work around this like so:

```
throw new ConstraintViolationException(
    new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(violations));
```

You may be interested in tracking [BVAL-198](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-198) which addresses this issue.

Comment: The constructor has been fixed as of Bean Validation 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known usability issue in Bean Validation 1.0.  This issue was addressed in [Bean Validation 1.1](https://beanvalidation.org/1.1/changes/) by issue [BVAL-198](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/BVAL-198), "Simplify creation of ConstraintViolationExceptions".  Upgrading to Bean Validation 1.1 or later will allow your code to compile as written.

The specific issue is that the [`ConstraintViolationException`](https://javadoc.io/static/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html#ConstraintViolationException(java.util.Set)) constructors accepted `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` for their `constraintViolations` parameter.  Since `Set<ConstraintViolation<Sample>>` is not a subtype of `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>`, it could not be passed into the constructor, with a compilation error occurring when attempting to do so.

Bean validation 1.1.0 [changed the constructors](https://javadoc.io/static/javax.validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/javax/validation/ConstraintViolationException.html#ConstraintViolationException(java.util.Set)) to instead accept `Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>>`.  As this is a supertype of `Set<ConstraintViolation<Sample>>`, it can be passed directly to the constructor.

As mentioned in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12099192/1108305), the fix while still on Bean Validation 1.0 was to pass in a `Set<ConstraintViolation<?>>` instead of `Set<ConstraintViolation<Sample>>`:

```java
throw new ConstraintViolationException(
    new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(violations));
```